# VBA Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” when trying to assign value to a variable

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

1st i explain what i'm trying to do. I have a workbook with many sheets and each of them have many named ranges. I want to loop through named ranges on a specific sheet and then hide/unhide them, if it has a specific name. At start i want to isolate the sheet and there i have the problem. I'm trying to get the name of the sheet, the range is on and assign that name to a variable. Here is the part of the code, i'm having problems with:

```
Dim rng as Name
Dim shP as String
for each rng in ThisWorkbook.Names
shp = rng.RefersToRange.Parent.Name 'here i get the error
... rest of the code ...
```

If i just `Debug.Print rng.RefersToRange.Parent.Name` instead in that line, i get the sheet name printed out in immediate window.
I also tried to `Dim shP as Variant` but it didn't helped.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a Name in the workbook that does not correspond to a block of cells.  Here I assign the Name `when` to the formula `=now()`

[image]

If I run:

```
Sub WhatsInaName()
    Dim nm As Name, s As String

    For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        MsgBox nm.RefersToRange.Parent.Name
    Next nm

End Sub
```

I also get a **1004**

You should first run:

```
Sub listum()

    With ActiveWorkbook
        If .Names.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To .Names.Count
                MsgBox (i & "  " & .Names(i).Name)
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

to verify each `Name` is a cell block.

Comment: Yes, you identified the problem correctly. One range lost it's cell block. Is there a way to check and skip those faulty ranges? I don't quite understand the point of your last code block.

Comment: @Ale  I would **temporarily** use some `OnError` logic to skip the "bad" `Names` ...........................in the long run you should remove them!

Comment: Ok, thx. In the long run all ranges will be proper. Just now, while i work on that file some of them may break. I think, i got my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a worksheet, then you need to use a `Worksheet` object.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Name
    Dim shP As Worksheet
    For Each rng In ThisWorkbook.Names
        Set shP = rng.RefersToRange.Parent 'here i get the error
    '... rest of the code ...
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Then you can use the `shP` as if it were a worksheet.

Comment: If i do that, i get the same error. I just want to get the name of the sheet, so i can compare it later on.

Comment: This worked for me with no errors, to get the name you just need to  use `shP.Name` whenever needed